# Number of ways to select AT LEAST one item from 12 different items. The items are divided into two sets, each of size 6

Tags: combinatorics

The answer says 4095. Now, as per my understanding :

$4095 = 2^{12} - 1$ == Ways of getting a non-null subset out of 12 elems

That would make sense, but where does the "divided into two sets, each of size 6" play in here ? Why does the answer still stay the same as it would if there was no further division of the bigger set ?

---

**Edit :**

Vladim's answer speaks of the following math :

[image: Rosen 7th edition : pg 417]

(Rosen 7th edition : pg 417)

Comment: What is the exact phrasing of the original question?

Comment: sorry... AT LEAST was missing in the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the same; however by doing the division in this manner (and forgetting about the non-null issue) you get a combinatorial proof of the following identity: $$2^{12}=\sum_{i=0}^6\sum_{j=0}^6 {6 \choose i}{6\choose j}$$

Comment: can you give some link to understand where that formula came from ? i don't have enough maths background unfortunately...

Comment: $i$ counts how many items to pick from the first group of six.  $j$ counts how many items to pick from the second group of six.